# Emulator everything is shown too large

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I'm new in programming.

I've made a app to play a little bit with the gridLayout but the emulator doesn't show it like the preview (emulator shows it too large/big). I don't have any idea what the reason is.

Thanks for any help :D

Preview in Emulator

[image]

Is there any possibility to change this in the android studio
or emulator setting or is there any problem with my xml that produce this fail ? I've looked more than 4 hours in the internet but don't find any issue like that and i've already uninstall and reinstall android Studio..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="397dp"
        android:layout_height="591dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="doyouspeakenglisch"
            android:text="Do you\nspeak English?" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="goodevening"
            android:text="Good evening" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="hello"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="howareyou"
            android:text="how are you?" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="ilivein"
            android:text="i live in..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="mynameis"
            android:text="My name is..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="please"
            android:text="Please" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="welcome"
            android:text="Welcome" />


    </GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines in the GridLayout are the problem:

```
android:layout_width="397dp"
android:layout_height="591dp"
```

Replace them with:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```